# android: chaotic selection in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application I have a `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`. When I select some one element in `ListView` I can see also few more selected elements.

Furthermore, when I scroll elements in `ListView` (after selection) then my selection disappears and elements are selected randomly.

Code of adapter:

```java
final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BinLocationsComponent>(activity, R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, locationComponents) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout.simple_test_layout_with_one_text_field, null);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
};
```

Looks like some parameters have to be set.

Could you please help me to avoid this problem?

---

**UPD1**

```java
final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BinLocationsComponent>(activity, R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, locationComponents) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LocationsViewHolder viewHolder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout.rp_bin_locations_block_element, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LocationsViewHolder();
            viewHolder.init(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (LocationsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final BinLocation binLocation = locationComponents.get(position).getBinLocation();
        if ( binLocation != null ) {
            viewHolder.provideValues(binLocation);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    class LocationsViewHolder {
        TextView stationName;
        TextView rackName;
        TextView binName;
        TextView volume;
        NumberPicker numberOfItems;

        public void init(View view) {
            stationName = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.ro_station_name);
            rackName = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.ro_rack_name);
            binName = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.ro_bin_name);
            volume = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.ro_volume_value);
            numberOfItems = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(id.ro_number_of_items);
        }

        public void provideValues(BinLocation location) {
            stationName.setText(location.getStationName());
            rackName.setText(location.getRackName());
            binName.setText(location.getBinName());
            volume.setText(valueOf(location.getVolume()));
        }

    }
};
```

and simple_list_item_multiple_choice it's android sdk's file:

```xml
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
/>
```

Comment: Please post `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml` source code for precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, its the first hurdle you face in your first `ListView`. Don't worry. First of all understand how `ListView` works, its important. Otherwise you can't master `ListView`.  In simplest word: `ListView` creates few row `View`s and utilizes them for every row. So if you have have 50 elements in your `ListView` then may be only 10 times `getView()` was called with convertView being null. So in short if you don't update the state of a view inside `getView()` method for every position, it will really be a chaos. Also please use View Holder Pattern in your `ListView`. It will drastically increase scrolling and will utilize less resources. More on View Holder Pattern http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

**UPDATE:**

I said

> So in short if you don't update the state of a view inside `getView()` method for every position, it will really be a chaos.

```
 private SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = new SparseBooleanArray();// class variable


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             if(checkedPositions.get(position)){
                 checkedPositions.put(position, false);
             }else{
                 checkedPositions.put(position, true);
             }
        }

    });
```

now in your `getView()`

```
((CheckedTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView)).setChecked(checkedPositions.get(position));
```

adjust this code according to your need. **OR** you can have a boolean variable in your `BinLocation` to maintain checked positions. But remember and understand the point of maintaining state inside `getView()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I changed code according to pattern, but still have problem.. Code is in update above..