# Text color changes of Row in List View when selected

Tags: android, android-listview, textcolor

I am facing this problem while selecting items in List view. What I am doing here is, when user selects item from List view, color of that item(here text) changes to CYAN (Default is Black). But, when I scroll List view, items which are not selected by user, their color also changes. I tried to resolved it, but have not find any solution. Below is my code..

### first.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>
```

### second.xml

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

### First.java

```
CheckedTextView chkText;    
SparseBooleanArray checked;     
lvDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    length_Friends = lvDialog.getCount();
                    checked = lvDialog.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    chkText = (CheckedTextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                    lvDialog.invalidateViews();

                    if(checked.get(arg2))
                    {
                        chkText.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                        colorRow ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chkText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        colorRow = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Above is the code, in which I used Checked Text View. What needs to be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use a custom ListAdapter and change color in "getView()".

Comment: can you provide some examples or Link.?

Comment: Have You written Adapter class?  If Yes, You have to write `onclicklistener` in that adapter class.. can you post the code in adapter?

Comment: I have tried to explain similar issue in detail here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486267/android-chaotic-selection-in-listview

Comment: `ListView` recycles `View`s, once you understand that you will know how to handle this situation.